# How to adjust the large space between two columns in tkinter?

Tags: python, tkinter

My code is as follows:
[Code](https://pastebin.com/EApkYqCT)

```
but = Button(root, text="Translate!", command= lambda : gtrans(tren.get()))
but.grid(row=2, column=2, padx=5, pady=5)
but2 = Button(root, text="Clear", command = lambda: reset())
but2.grid(row=2, column=3, padx=5, pady=5)
```

And my output is as follows:
[This is what appears when i extend a 300x300 window](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yYs06.jpg)

Please Help

Comment: [Did you check this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39555194/how-to-add-space-between-two-widgets-placed-in-grid-in-tkinter-python)

Comment: Please describe what you expect. Do you want the buttons further apart? Closer together? It's not clear what you want changed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you follow your pastebin, you can see that both your label and entry are also in col = 2 (i.e. same as 'Translate!' button). So the issue is not a big gap between columns(the gap between Entry window and the 'Clear' button is rather small). The issue is the width of col2 is fitting your label.

What you could do:

- Add columnspan = 2 to both Entry and Label (thus these elements will
  span over column 2 and column 3) as `lab.grid(row=0, column=2, columnspan = 2)` and `tren.grid(row=1, column=2, columnspan = 2)`
- Following [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36357132/13590089) you could add sticky = 'E' on your
  'Translate!' button to move it to the right edge of column 2, thus
  reducing gap between the two buttons (I'm not sure if it would look
  the best, but it depends how you want it to be)

Comment: Does sticky come under the grid or the definition of the button?

Comment: grid, so it would look something like  `but.grid(sticky = 'E', row=2, column=2, padx=5, pady=5)`